# Google-colaboratory kernel dies when SVD is attempted

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to perform SVD for the MNIST data set on a google-colaboratory python 2 environment. Below is my code,

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
import numpy as np

mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')

U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(mnist.data)
```

Once the above code is run, the kernel gets restarted after a message as:

> Runtime died. Automatically restarting.

Am I doing anything wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you're running out of RAM on the VM.

Depending on what you want to do, `numpy` offers you two ways to reduce the amount of data returned -- from [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html#numpy.linalg.svd):

- you can pass `compute_uv=False` to completely skip computing the unitary matrices `U` and `V`, or
- you can pass `full_matrices=False` to avoid computing the full `U` and `V` matrices.

In particular, with `full_matrices=True`, `U` is a `70000x70000` matrix, which is what's causing the out of memory woes.

Comment: Is there any way that I can request to increase the memory allocation for my VM? `!free -g` says that there's only about 6GB free. I was hoping to run on a bit larger data set. Perhaps colab isn't the right place.